# Accessing a app.config file property in another app.config file

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, app-config

I have a WCF class library which implements a Windows Service business logic.In `app.config` 
file i defined a property called "debug mode" for debugging purposes.

Then i have created separate Windows Service and where i used above created WCF class 
library as a reference(by adding `.dll` file and "using name" statement).

I need to set "debug mode" property in wcf class library `app.config` file using Windows service `app.config` files.

is it possible ? or do i have any alternate method.

Comment: Copy and paste is how .NET has done this since day 1. Copy the settings out of the WCF library .config file and paste into the windows service config file.

Comment: Thanks John.It works fine after copying that..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `appSettings` and `ConfigurationManager` to read your property, you **have** to put (copy - as @JohnSounders explaine) your property into your windows service config file.

In other case - you'll not be able to retrieve it from config.

In usual way, your application will look for configuration of current running executable (in your case - windows service).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am not using ConfigurationManager and appSettings .I am using  Properties.Settings.Default.MyProp method. but  still it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have one app.config and both the WCF library and the windows service can read from it. The windows service is the current thread and references the WCF library so the WCF library has access to the windows service's app.config.

Comment: Ya know, I saw that Aslam Jiffry was a new user and thought that there might be a novice element involved in this problem, that is why I used the word "should" in my answer. My hypothesis only takes a minute to test. Would you have marked me down if it was a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Your hypothesis is just plain wrong. Experiment on your own time, and don't post your speculations here - either as a comment or an answer.